# what is dollar sign mean in the stack frames when debugging?

Tags: java, eclipse

In the stack using Eclipse, sometimes I saw

Manager$2.run() line : 278

What does $2 mean here?

Comment: Every time you creating anonymous class java gives name to it automatically. `Manager$2` is some anonymous class inside `Manager` class

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is anonymous class.

> An *anonymous class* is a local class without a name. An anonymous class
>   is defined and instantiated in a single succinct expression using the
>   *new* operator.

From the method name, it might be a [Runnable.run()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html#run%28%29) method.

```
public class Manager {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Manager();
    }
    
    public Manager() {
        //                         this is anonymous class
        //                              |
        //                              V
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("hi");
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

See

- [Anonymous Classes](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm)

Comment: @DaveNewton not anything with a run. It has to be anonymous